# A single mongoose query for all objects in an array

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I've got the following array of objects (more than 500 objects) obtained from a mongodb collection:

```
var rentals = [{
    deviceId: 1,
    start_date: ISODate("2018-05-10T10:11:23.143Z") ,
    end_date: ISODate("2018-07-11T12:19:53.143Z")
},{
    deviceId: 2,
    start_date: ISODate("2018-03-09T10:11:23.143Z") ,
    end_date: ISODate("2018-03-10T12:19:53.143Z")
},{
    deviceId: 2,
    start_date: ISODate("2018-03-11T10:11:23.143Z") ,
    end_date: ISODate("2018-05-12T12:19:53.143Z")
},{
    deviceId: 3,
    start_date: ISODate("2018-01-10T10:11:23.143Z") ,
    end_date: ISODate("2018-09-11T12:19:53.143Z")
},{
...
}]
```

I've got the following readings schema in Mongoose:

```
var readingSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    deviceId: Number,
    timestamp: Date,
    data: String
});
```

Currently 100k readings in the DB.

Readings documents Example:

```
[{
    deviceId: 1,
    timestamp: ISODate("2018-05-11T10:11:23.143Z"),
    data: 'wathever'
},{
    deviceId: 2,
    timestamp: ISODate("2018-03-10T00:00:00.000Z"),
    data: 'wathever'
},{
    deviceId: 2,
    timestamp: ISODate("2018-03-09T23:00:00.000Z"),
    data: 'wathever'
},{
    deviceId: 2,
    timestamp: ISODate("2018-05-18T00:00:00.000Z"),
    data: 'wathever'
},{
    deviceId: 3,
    timestamp: ISODate("2018-01-07T00:00:00.000Z"),
    data: 'wathever'
},{
...
}]
```

I need to iterate through the rentals array, and for each rental get the readings of that device that where made between the rental's start_date and the rentals end_date. I need a single readings array as a result.

My solution is iterating through rentals array and doing a query for reach rental.

```
var allReadings = [];
Async.each(rentals, function(rental, callback) {
        Reading.find({
            timestamp: {
                "$lte": new Date(rental.end_date)
            },
            timestamp: {
                "$gte": new Date(rental.start_date)
            },
            "deviceId": { rental.deviceId } 
        },
        function(err, readings) {
            allReadings.push(readings);
            callback();
        });  

}, function(err){
    console.log(allReadings);
});
```

Is there a way of doing a single Mongoose query and get the same result so that it is performance optimised?
I guess I need to use aggregation but can't think of a way of querying this.

So in the example data the result should be:

```
[{
    deviceId: 1,
    timestamp: ISODate("2018-05-11T10:11:23.143Z"),
    data: 'wathever'
},{
    deviceId: 2,
    timestamp: ISODate("2018-03-10T00:00:00.000Z"),
    data: 'wathever'
},{
    deviceId: 2,
    timestamp: ISODate("2018-03-09T23:00:00.000Z"),
    data: 'wathever'
}]
```

Edit: the query in sql would be:

```
SELECT rea.*
FROM   ren
INNER JOIN readings rea
ON ren.devideId = rea.deviceId AND ren.start_date <= rea.fecha AND ren.end_date >= rea.timestamp
```

Comment: Possible dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3985214/retrieve-only-the-queried-element-in-an-object-array-in-mongodb-collection. Use `$filter`

Comment: @Veeram I am not sure if your link helps..how do you look for all the rentals in the array at once?

Comment: You look one array value at a time using $filter and output the array elements which match your query criteria.

Comment: So what should be the output from the above document?

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet the output should be array of readings

Comment: Can you please give me the criteria and the output from the above array... Criteria in the sense start and end date

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet I edited the OP with more example data. The criteria is: I need to obtain all the readings which timestamp is between start_date-end_date of a rental and deviceId matches with the rental too. Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet added sql equivalent

Comment: have you tried [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) ? Something like `db.rentals.aggregate([
   {
     $lookup:
       {
         from: "readings",
         localField: "deviceId",
         foreignField: "deviceId",
         as: "mreadings"
       }
  },
  {$unwind:"$mreadings"},
  {$match:{"start_date":{$lte:"$mreadings.timestamp"},"end_date":{$gte:"$mreadings.timestamp"} }
])`